# Windows Azure: Error 300 Ambiguous Redirect when creating a blob container

Tags: windows, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I followed a tutorial on creating a blob on windows azure. But when I do that, I get an exception error:

> Error while creating containerThe server encountered an unknown failure: The remote server returned an error: (300) Ambiguous Redirect.

The code is:

```
private void SetContainersAndPermission()
{
    try
    {
        // create a container
        var CloudAccountStorage = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("BlobConnectionString");
        cloudBlobClient = CloudAccountStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("documents");
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();

        // permissions
        var containerPermissions = blobContainer.GetPermissions();
        containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;
        blobContainer.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error while creating container" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me How to solve this problem....

Comment: this is the connection string

<Setting name="BlobConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />

Comment: were you able to fix this ? my container is also giving the same error (exception )

Comment: I wasn't able to fix it.. It didn't work on my local system but it worked on windows azure directly....

Comment: I don't understand ... you used a worker role or something ?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the connection string is somehow wrong?  Can you share the connection string?  (X out your shared key...)

You could also install Fiddler (debugging HTTP proxy) and see what the HTTP request looks like.  That may make the issue more obvious.

Comment: Could you please tell me How to share the connection string...

I just followed this tutorial
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/saurabh122/516/

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I am not sure if this is the workaround for it. I modified the container name value in ServiceConfiguration.csfg from "Photograph" to "photograph" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not give upper case letters in queue, table or blob name. The name should have only lower case characters.